# UIView overrideUserInterfaceStyle is not working

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, darkmode

I want the app to adhere to the system light/dark modes, but one child view to be stuck to light mode.

So technically, this should work:

```
myChildView.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

This does not work!

---

So there are a few methods to override the interface style:

```
UIApplication.current.windows.first.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

This works where it locks the whole app to light mode.

---

```
myViewController.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

This does not work in any of my view controllers.

---

```
myViewControlller.view.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

This also doesn't work.

---

```
myChildView.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

This is what I need to work, but doesn't.

I also do not have it specified in the info.plist to lock the whole app into any mode.

Am I missing something?

### UPDATE

The issue is still present on iOS 15 or iOS 16 betas. Above methods don't seem to work:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/appearance_customization/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface/choosing_a_specific_interface_style_for_your_ios_app

Comment: When you say `one child view` ... do you mean a ***`subview`***? Or do you mean a ***child view controller***?

Comment: @DonMag one sub view to be locked in to light mode.

Comment: Hmmm... this seems to work? https://pastebin.com/m9j4uGTJ -- result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az7Ro.png

Comment: @DonMag that’s overriding the sub view. Which I tried above and did not work for some reason.

Comment: Well... it worked for me, so it should work for you. If you post a [mre] we can try to figure out what's different.

Answer (score 2):

I use this with `UITraitCollection(userInterfaceLevel: .elevated)` but should work just as well with userInterfaceStyle. (You will get some logs saying you shouldn't override traitCollection, just ignore them)

```swift
override var traitCollection: UITraitCollection {
  UITraitCollection(traitsFrom: [super.traitCollection, UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .light)])
}
```

The documentation for what you are trying to use mentions some exceptions, I don't know if that is what makes it not work for you: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/3238086-overrideuserinterfacestyle

> If you assign a different value, the new style applies to the view and all of the subviews owned by the same view controller. (If the view hierarchy contains the root view of an embedded child view controller, the child view controller and its views do not inherit the interface style.)